# how to get current url, on exit event InAppBrowser, Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, inappbrowser

I am trying to implement a solution where I need to get the current url on exit event of InAppBowser Ionic2.

My Code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {
  browser:any;
  exit:boolean = false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  startPayment(){
    this.browser = new InAppBrowser('https://ionic.io', '_blank','location=no,toolbar=no,hardwareback=no,EnableViewPortScale=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done');
    this.browser.on("exit")
            .subscribe(
            (e) => {
                this.checkpaymentStatus(e);
            },
            err => {
                console.log("InAppBrowser loadstart Event Error: " + err);
            });
  };

  checkpaymentStatus(e){
    console.log(e);
    console.log("in app browser exit")
    this.exit = true;
  }    
};//
```

The exit event is firing properly but I am unable to get the url in event(e), it just gives Object{type:exit}.

Please tell me , how can I get the url on exit.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use `e.url`

```
checkpaymentStatus(e){
    console.log(e.url); // you will get url here
    // ... ... ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I use e.url, I am getting un defined.

Comment: which version of ionic are you using? api of ionic 2 and 3 differ.

Comment: I am using ionic2